# Running python code by clicking a button in Bokeh

Tags: python, button, bokeh, jupyter

Does anyone have an example of how to run python code in jupyter by clicking a button in Bokeh?

Comment: [documentation](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/notebook.html)

Comment: This is similar to what i am trying to accomplish but related to select items and much more involved: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/stock_applet/stock_app_simple.py

Comment: The answer here is great. You should accept it if you feel it has answered your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE** The original answer was very out of date. The answer has been updated to reflect changes since Bokeh `0.11` which was released in January of 2016.

A complete example pared from the sliders demo, that uses features from Bokeh `0.12.4`:

```
from numpy import linspace, pi, sin

from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure

# Set up data
x = linspace(0, 4*pi, 200) 
y = sin(x)
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

# Set up plot
plot = figure(x_range=(0, 4*pi), y_range=(-2.5, 2.5))
plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

# Set up widgets
amplitude = Slider(title="amplitude", value=1.0, start=-5.0, end=5.0)
freq = Slider(title="frequency", value=1.0, start=0.1, end=5.1)

# Set up callbacks
def update(attrname, old, new):
    # Get the current slider values
    a = amplitude.value
    k = freq.value

    # Update the data for the new curve
    source.data = dict(x=x, y=a*sin(k*x))

amplitude.on_change('value', update)
freq.on_change('value', update)

# Set up layout and add to document
inputs = widgetbox(amplitude, freq)
curdoc().add_root(row(inputs, plot, width=1200))
```

---

Run with `bokeh serve --show <filename>` and get the following responsive web app in your browser:

[image: Simplified Bokeh Sliders demo]

Comment: This was really helpful.   I appreciate it.

Comment: Note that the new version of bokeh-server should make this easier/nicer, but I haven't played with it yet.

Comment: any change we can get an update?  bokeh-server was removed after version 0.10.

Comment: Looks like thorough documentation here http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html

Comment: Updated to reflect current `bokeh serve` in use since January 2016 (Bokeh `0.11` and newer)

Comment: Nice answer but for sliders. The OP asked for Button.

Comment: These days there is panel: https://panel.holoviz.org/user_guide/Widgets.html